# How to reference a variable using a string

Tags: java

I am attempting to reference a variable using a certain string but have no idea how to do it. I know that I can use if statements if I really had to but I am sure that there is a simple way. An example is a Integer named dog. I would try to access the Integer using another string that contained the text dog.

```
  private int dog;
    String anything = "dog";
```

Is there anyway this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: @AVD I think he's going to need a bit more explanation than that. Perhaps you could post a code sample?

Comment: Gosh, this has never been asked before. Sigh...

Comment: It's possible (through either a map or reflection), but could you justify why you want to do this?

Comment: I am creating a server for a game and need to reference each player through their specific client ID, in order to update their position.

Comment: @Silver: then use a map, but don't try to use variables this way. Variables are not nearly as important as you think and in fact almost don't exist in compiled code. What matters most is **references** and that is what a map will do for you. Search the site for similar questions (something you should have done to begin with since this questino gets asked daily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// use a map for referring to a value given its name
Map<String, Integer> vars = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

// for example, let's use these values
String anything = "dog";
int dog = 10;

// bind a value to a name
vars.put(anything, dog);

// retrieve the value, given its name
vars.get(anything);
=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, MyObject> mapping = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Or `new HashMap<String, MyObject>();` for pre java 7

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) of String to Integer. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  java.util.Map<String, Integer> dogMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();
  dogMap.put("Snoop", 10);
  dogMap.put("doggy", 15);
  dogMap.put("dog", 20);

  System.out.println(dogMap);
}
```

Which outputs

```
{doggy=15, Snoop=10, dog=20}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two options: create a `Map<String, Object>` that connects the two, or use reflection. I prefer reflection.

in order to get the field:

```
public class Test {
    private int dog = 10;
    private String anything = "dog";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test obj = new Test();
        Object field = obj.getClass()
                          .getDeclaredField(obj.anything)
                          .get(obj);            
        System.out.println(field);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 10

Create an object of the class that you will use. Then use the `getDeclaredField()` method on the class of that object. This will look into the `private` fields that are set, `getField()` holds only the `public` fields. That's it.

I've removed the try-catch from the post because it just clutters it.